# How to troubleshoot IndexerEnv::putrangeindex:XDMP:parent link :invalid parent link node doc("xx/xx")//xx

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

We are continuously getting below Debug level log as of now I'm not sure it will cause any issue...

> 2022-01-27 16:13:55.705 Debug: IndexerEnv::putRangeIndex: XDMP:parent link :invalid parent link node doc("xx/xx")//xx
>
> 2021-01-24 16:13:55.715 Debug: IndexerEnv::putRangeIndex: XDMP:parent link :invalid parent link node doc("xx/xx")//xx

Can anyone help how to resolve this and it will create any performance issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that you have a fragment, but the document for that URI is missing.

https://docs.marklogic.com/10.0/messages/XDMP-en/XDMP-PARENTLINK

> **Message Text**
>
> Invalid parent link node doc("variable1")//variable2
>
> **Cause**
>
> A parent fragment in a fragmented document is missing.
>
> **Response**
>
> The document must be reloaded.

You may need to look and see what sort of fragment it is (document-properties, document-lock, or if you have [fragmentation rules](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/fragments#chapter) to split documents into multiple fragments) and the history of changes for such documents.

Comment: thanks for the heads-up @Mads Hansen, this continuous log will create any performance issues?

Comment: Not necessarily that it will cause a performance issue, but may indicate that something isn't right with your data. It would be good to understand how/why you have those orphaned fragments and decide if you should delete them or attempt to repair/re-insert those docs.

Comment: In the past (a few years ago) I had a similar issue. Related to parent of fragment roots. In this case, the documents were not missing. However, there was an issue with the schema definition  that seemed to cause the children not to resolve. So beyond a fragment parent missing - if fragment root or parent set, perhaps have a look at the schema references in the parent fragment.